# How to create multiple tables using terraform in the Bigquery GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform

I am new to terraform. Please let me know where I am doing wrong. Below is my main.tf code:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "demo" {
  dataset_id                  = "${var.db_id}"
  friendly_name               = "${var.friendly_name}"
  location                    = "${var.region}"
  default_table_expiration_ms = "3600000"
  labels = {
    env = "default"
  }
}
resource "google_bigquery_table" "demo" {
  dataset_id = "${var.db_id}"
  table_id   = "${var.table}"
  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY"
  }
  labels = {
    env = "default"
  }
  schema = <<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "br_op_inventory_a",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "state",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
]
EOF
}

resource "google_bigquery_table" "devops" {
  dataset_id = "${var.db_id}"
  table_id   = "${var.table_1}"
  time_partitioning {
    type = "DAY"
  }
  labels = {
    env = "default"
  }
  schema = <<EOF
[
  {
    "name": "br_op_inventory_a",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  },
  {
    "name": "state",
    "type": "STRING",
    "mode": "NULLABLE"
  }
]
EOF
}
```

and here is my variables.tf code:

```
variable "friendly_name" {
    default="test"
    }
variable "region" {
    default="asia-south1"
    }
variable "db_id" {
    default="operation_performance_test_2"
    }
variable "table" {
    default="sample_demo"
    }
variable "table_1" {
    default="price_inventory"
    }
```

everything works fine when I run terraform init and terraform plan commands. But, when I try to run terraform apply command, I get the following error:

```
google_bigquery_table.demo: Creating...
google_bigquery_table.devops: Creating...
google_bigquery_dataset.demo: Creation complete after 4s [id=projects/midyear-cursor-264117/datasets/operation_performance_test_2]

Error: googleapi: Error 404: Not found: Dataset midyear-cursor-264117:operation_performance_test_2, notFound

  on main.tf line 10, in resource "google_bigquery_table" "demo":
  10: resource "google_bigquery_table" "demo" {



Error: googleapi: Error 404: Not found: Dataset midyear-cursor-264117:operation_performance_test_2, notFound

  on main.tf line 35, in resource "google_bigquery_table" "devops":
  35: resource "google_bigquery_table" "devops" {
```

When I again try to run terraform apply command, both the tables get created. Below is the console:

```
google_bigquery_table.devops: Creating...
google_bigquery_table.demo: Creating...
google_bigquery_table.devops: Creation complete after 3s [id=projects/midyear-cursor-264117/datasets/operation_performance_test_2/tables/price_inventory]
google_bigquery_table.demo: Creation complete after 4s [id=projects/midyear-cursor-264117/datasets/operation_performance_test_2/tables/sample_demo]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed
```

Why doesn't the tables get created when I run the terraform apply command the first time ?
Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: It seems that `dataset` creation is a bit delayed in Bigquery runtime, thus all the requests with `table` spreading are just suspended with the above mentioned error. You can consider adjusting the code with [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html#depends_on-explicit-output-dependencies) argument leveraging dependency in runpath.

Comment: If you find this comment useful, pls accept/up vote below my answer, helping more Stack contributors with their researches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quoting my comment as an answer in order to support further contributors with their research on the same subject.

In your current scenario `dataset` creation is a bit delayed in Bigquery runtime, thus all the requests with `tables` spreading are just suspended with the above mentioned error. You can consider adjusting Terraform code with [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html#depends_on-explicit-output-dependencies) argument leveraging dependency in the desired run path.